# Access Structure Secret Sharing -- How to find complement of an access structure?

Tags: monotone-access-structure

I'm looking for the complement definition of an access structure $AS$. I'm lost trying to find the complement of $AS$, $\overline{AS}$. Can someone explain what exactly is happening or provide a source for this?

$P = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4 \}$

$AS =\{\{p_1,p_2,p_4 \}, \{p_1,p_3,p_4\}, \{p_2,p_3\}\}$

$\overline{AS} =\{\{p_1,p_2\}, \{p_1,p_3\}, \{p_1,p_4\}, \{p_2,p_4\}, \{p_3,p_4\}\}$

$t = |\overline{AS}| =5$

Comment: You can easily write this with some little knowledge $\LaTeX$.

Comment: It should be the dual [Lecture Notes in Secret Sharing](https://web.mat.upc.edu/carles.padro/arc02v03.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.

Comment: I would be happy if you write an answer.

Comment: I'll try to update later. Thank you.